# find all possible 3 number combinations where sum is less than a given number using R

Tags: r, dynamic, combinations

I have following set of numbers 10,17,5,7,15. From these numbers, I need to find the all possible 3 number combinations where the sum is less than or equal to 35. within a one such combination , a specific number should not contain more than once.
 Ex : 10 ,10 ,5 is an incorrect combination since 10 repeated twice.

I tried this code but its not giving what i need.

```
library(data.table)
df=expand.grid(x1=c(10,17,5,7,15),
               x2=c(10,17,5,7,15),
               x3=c(10,17,5,7,15)
               )
setDT(df)
df[(x1+x2+x3) <= 35]
```

A part of the output of the above code as follows,

```
  x1 x2 x3
 1: 10 10 10
 2:  5 10 10
 3:  7 10 10
 4: 15 10 10
 5:  5 17 10
 6:  7 17 10
 7: 10  5 10
```

based on the above output it can be observed that one number appears more than once. 
can anyone suggest a hint to get the desired results ?

thank you

Comment: Hint: just filter the least afterwards...

Comment: Maybe `df %>% mutate(flag1=apply(.,1,n_distinct), flag2=rowSums(.)) %>% filter(flag1==3 & flag2<=35)`

Comment: An `8` has crept into your code twice instead of `5` so I have corrected this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following to see if it's what the question asks for.

```
x <- c(10,17,5,7,15)
i <- combn(x, 3, sum) <= 35

combn(x, 3)[, i]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]   10   10   10   10   10   17    5
#[2,]   17   17    5    5    7    5    7
#[3,]    5    7    7   15   15    7   15
```

The above is the general idea. A more efficient implementation, both memory and speed wise, is `f2` below.

```
f1 <- function(x, n = 3, thres = 35){
  i <- combn(x, n, sum) <= thres
  combn(x, n)[, i]
}
f2 <- function(x, n = 3, thres = 35){
  cmb <- combn(x, n)
  cmb[, colSums(cmb) <= thres]
}
```

Check if the results are all with different numbers.

```
res <- f2(x)
apply(res, 2, function(y){
  all(y[-1] != y[1])
})
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

identical(f1(x), f2(x))
#[1] TRUE
```

Now time the functions.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(x), 
                               f2 = f2(x))
#Unit: microseconds
# expr     min      lq      mean   median      uq     max neval cld
#   f1 105.150 107.383 110.66616 108.6535 109.896 238.899   100   b
#   f2  62.779  65.568  67.65754  66.4290  67.145 122.119   100  a
```

Comment: Not that it matters (it will not change the seven cases you found), but the original question was `<= 35` rather than `< 35`

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I had missed that point. Will edit. Anyway, the functions would still work, but making `thres = 36` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The function `comboGeneral` from the package `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) was designed specifically for this task.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
x <- c(10,17,5,7,15)

comboGeneral(x, 3, 
             constraintFun = "sum",
             comparisonFun = "<=",
             limitConstraints = 35)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7   10
[2,]    5    7   15
[3,]    5    7   17
[4,]    5   10   15
[5,]    5   10   17
[6,]    7   10   15
[7,]    7   10   17
```

It is very efficient as well. Observe:

```
set.seed(42)
s <- sample(100, 25)
s
[1] 92 93 29 81 62 50 70 13 61 65 42 91 83 23 40 80 88 10 39 46 73 11 78 85  7

system.time(a <- comboGeneral(s, 10, 
                              constraintFun = "sum",
                              comparisonFun = "<=",
                              limitConstraints = 600))
 user  system elapsed 
0.232   0.046   0.278

dim(a)
[1] 2252362      10
```

Compared to the more efficient function `f2` posted by @RuiBarradas and `dt_checker` by @Cole:

```
system.time(b <- f2(s, 10, 600))
 user  system elapsed 
3.283   0.093   3.418

system.time(a2 <- dt_checker(s, 10, 600))
 user  system elapsed 
1.803   0.319   0.646
```

It should also be noted that the algorithm behind `comboGeneral` terminates as soon as a solution can longer be obtained. Consequently, the timings will be different with different constraints. Observe:

```
system.time(a <- comboGeneral(s, 10, 
                              constraintFun = "sum",
                              comparisonFun = "<=",
                              limitConstraints = 400))
 user  system elapsed 
0.003   0.001   0.003
```

However, with the other solutions, all combinations must be created and then filtered (which doesn't take as long), thus the timings are similar to before.

```
system.time(b <- f2(s, 10, 400))
 user  system elapsed 
2.933   0.039   2.973

system.time(a2 <- dt_checker(s, 10, 400))
 user  system elapsed 
1.786   0.276   0.627
```

As a final benchmark, we benchmark finding all results on multiple restraints:

```
system.time(a <- lapply(seq(200, 600, 25), function(x) {
    t <- comboGeneral(s, 10, 
                      constraintFun = "sum",
                      comparisonFun = "<=",
                      limitConstraints = x)
    dim(t)
}))
 user  system elapsed 
0.498   0.125   0.623

system.time(a2 <- lapply(seq(200, 600, 25), function(x) {
    t <- dt_checker(s, 10, x)
    dim(t)
}))
  user  system elapsed 
34.448   4.633  10.693

identical(a, a2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Didn't know about package `RcppAlgos`. I will check it out, seems promising.

Comment: Even before your edit I thought your function in your package was great. Very impressive.

Answer (score 4):

We can remove rows with `any` `duplicated` value and then select rows with sum `<= 35`

```
df1 <- df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(x))), ]
df1[rowSums(df1) <= 35, ]

#    x1 x2 x3
#8    5 17 10
#9    7 17 10
#12  17  8 10
#13   5  8 10
#14   7  8 10
```

Original `df` in OP's code has all possible combinations of `c(10,17,5,7,15)` with lot of repetitions. Using the `apply` loop we remove any rows with repeated values. So a row with 10, 10 would get deleted and same with 17, 17 and other repetitions. `df1` is the dataframe without repeating numbers. Now we subset only those rows whose sum is less than equal to 35.

Comment: Too late and can't quite follow. Could you please elaborate the logic behind this?

Comment: @NelsonGon Added some explanation. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You may not want to do this with more columns, but this works simply:

```
df[(x1+x2+x3) <= 35 & x1 != x2 & x2 != x3 & x3 != x1]
```

and if you think 10,17,5 is the same as 5,10,17 so they need only be kept once, then:

```
df[(x1+x2+x3) <= 35 & x1 < x2 & x2 < x3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer that relies on `data.table`'s non-equi joins. Most of the time is spent manipulating character vectors in order to evaluate in the `dt` call.

```
library(data.table)

dt_checker <- function(y, n, criteria) {
  x_dt <- data.table(x1 = y)
  setkey(x_dt, x1)

  x_res <- copy(x_dt)[seq_len(length(y)-(n-1))]


  for (i in seq_len(n)[-1]) {
    setnames(x_dt, paste0('x', i))

    cols <- paste0('x', seq_len(i))
    cols2 <- cols
    cols2[i-1] <- paste0('x.', cols2[i-1])

    x_res <- x_res[x_dt, on = paste(cols[c(i-1, i)], collapse = '<'), ..cols2, allow.cartesian = T, nomatch = 0L]
    setnames(x_res, cols)
  }

  x_res[x_res[, rowSums(.SD)<= criteria] ,]
}

dt_checker(x, 3, 35)
   x1 x2 x3
1:  5  7 10
2:  5  7 15
3:  5 10 15
4:  7 10 15
5:  5  7 17
6:  5 10 17
7:  7 10 17
```

I mainly did it to see if I could get `data.table` faster than the `RcppAlgos` solution. I couldn't and in the time I spent figuring out the logic to automate all of these joins, I probably could have figured it out in `Rcpp` :).

```
system.time(a <- comboGeneral(s, 10, 
+                               constraintFun = "sum",
+                               comparisonFun = "<=",
+                               limitConstraints = 600))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.10    0.13    0.23 
system.time(a2 <- dt_checker(s, 10, 600))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.54    0.09    0.57 
system.time(a3 <- f2(s, 10, 600))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.98    0.00    4.01
```

Also, for smaller datasets, this would work as well. But for smaller datasets, @Rui's solution is almost as fast as the `RcppAlgos` and it's a base solution.

```
dt_CJ <- function(y, n, criteria) {
  x <- sort(y)
  dt_res <- do.call(CJ, lapply(seq(1, length(x) - (n-1)), function(i) x[i:(i+n-1)]))

  eval_crit <- paste0(lapply(1:(n-1), function(i) paste0('V', i:(i+1), collapse = '<')), collapse = '&')
  dt_res[eval(parse(text = eval_crit)), .SD[rowSums(.SD) <= criteria]][]
}

Unit: microseconds
                  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 dt_checker(x, 3, 600) 5074.100 5075.601 5333.7608 5139.000 5322.201 6057.902     5
      dt_CJ(x, 3, 600) 2593.001 2662.801 2703.7010 2670.901 2770.101 2821.701     5
         f2(x, 3, 600)   72.601   76.001   90.7412   79.101   81.702  144.301     5
              comboGen   45.000   47.501   69.4604   58.701   69.000  127.100     5
```